# Use conditions in IAM policy after Switch Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We are trying to use conditions to control access in AWS. The JSON returned after the first switch to AWSRole does not contain the UserName param and the conditions are not working for username.

ie. After User1 and User2 switches to AWSRole put conditions :

Sample policy in AWSRole which allows you to switch to subRoles

```
"Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::661222050851:role/SubRole1"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:UserName": [
                    "User1","User2"]



"Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::661222050851:role/SubRole2"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:UserName": ["User2"]
```

They contain other attributes like principalid and arn which gives details on which user is trying to assume the role but these keys are not available to be used in IAM conditions

```
"principalId": "AROAIZAHZM7GWabc:User1"
"arn": "arn:aws:sts::accid:assumed-role/SubRole1/User1
```